# How to execute different functions using ngClick based on the number of clicks?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am wondering if it is possible to make `ngClick` take two different functions, depending on number of clicks user has clicked this specific `ngClick`?

I was thinking about applying some modulo logic, however, I couldn't find any resources on that.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not track click count in your controller/directive, call one function from `ngClick` and decide which other function to call inside that one? This is much cleaner and simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="doFunction()">Click me!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var counter = 0;

    $scope.doFunction = function() {
        if(counter % 2 === 0)
            console.log('Do func a');
        else
            console.log('Do func b');

        counter++;
    }   
}]);
```

Comment: Yeah, I was implementing this approach, but somehow didn't find it to be 'angular-way'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is correct doing it in the `ngClick` directly. If you want to create a function with logic based on the number of clicks, then maybe the logic should be handled in the function itself, using conditions.

For example, you could have this HTML:

```
<a ng-click="newClick()">Click!</a>
```

With this Angular:

```
$scope.newClick = () => {
  if(numberOfClicks whatever)
    // Some logic
  else if(numberOfClicks whatever)
    //Some other logic
};
```